# Trouble updating QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I have a running application that will take a CSV file and take out all the email addresses and display them on a QTableWidget. Unfortunately, it is only capable of doing this once. If I go back to select another CSV file the email TableWidget won't update, and the parameters will carry over to EmailList. This is also why I cannot init_ui in the constructer method of EmailList. I was wondering how the display can be updated, repeatedly with new file input. Here is an appropriate CSV file to run yourself. http://www.sharecsv.com/s/ed7c7a2154478339603a192921a352eb/csv_test.csv

email_list.py

```
import sys
import os
import re
import io
from construct import ConstructMessage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QTableWidget,QTableWidgetItem, QVBoxLayout,QHBoxLayout, QWidget, QAction, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, pyqtSignal, QFileInfo, QDir 

class EmailList(QWidget):

    buttonClicked = pyqtSignal()
    email_list = []

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("Initzd")       
        #self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.v_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.h_layout = QHBoxLayout()        

        self.email_widget = QTableWidget()
        self.email_widget.setColumnCount(1)          

        for row_data in EmailList.email_list:
            print("Email list: " + row_data)
            row = self.email_widget.rowCount()
            self.email_widget.insertRow(row)
            for column, col in enumerate(row_data):
                item = QTableWidgetItem(row_data)
                self.email_widget.setItem(row, column, item)  


        width = 200        
        self.open_button = QPushButton("Open")
        self.open_button.setMaximumWidth(width)
        self.continue_button = QPushButton("Continue")
        self.continue_button.setMaximumWidth(width)
        self.back_button = QPushButton("Go back")
        self.back_button.setMaximumWidth(width) 

        self.open_button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.open_click(self.open_button,"Open",self.widget))
        self.continue_button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.continue_click(self.continue_button,"Continue"))
        self.back_button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.on_back_clicked())          


        self.v_layout.addWidget(self.email_widget)               
        self.h_layout.addWidget(self.open_button)
        self.h_layout.addWidget(self.continue_button)
        self.h_layout.addWidget(self.back_button)

        self.v_layout.addLayout(self.h_layout)

        self.setLayout(self.v_layout)
        self.setWindowTitle("Email List") 
        print("Welcome to the email_list widget")

        self.show()      

    def on_back_clicked(self):
        print("You are going back")
        self.buttonClicked.emit()

    def update_emails(self, imported_email_list):
        EmailList.email_list = imported_email_list

    def continue_click(self,continue_button,string):
        pass

from sheet import Sheet
```

sheet.py

```
import sys
import os
import re
import io
import csv
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QVBoxLayout,QHBoxLayout, QWidget, QAction, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, pyqtSignal, QFileInfo, QDir 

class Sheet(QWidget):

    buttonClicked = pyqtSignal()
    email_list = []

    def __init__(self,r,c):
        super().__init__() 
        self.init_ui(r,c)

    def init_ui(self,r,c):
        self.v_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.h_layout = QHBoxLayout()

        self.sheet = QTableWidget()
        self.sheet.setRowCount(r)
        self.sheet.setColumnCount(c)

        width = 200        
        self.open_button = QPushButton("Open")
        self.open_button.setMaximumWidth(width)
        self.continue_button = QPushButton("Continue")
        self.continue_button.setMaximumWidth(width)

        self.file_path = None

        self.open_button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.open_click(self.open_button,"Open",self.sheet))    
        self.continue_button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.continue_click(self.continue_button,"Continue"))    

        self.v_layout.addWidget(self.sheet)               
        self.h_layout.addWidget(self.open_button)
        self.h_layout.addWidget(self.continue_button)

        self.v_layout.addLayout(self.h_layout)

        self.setLayout(self.v_layout)
        self.setWindowTitle("CSV Reader")        

        self.show()

    def continue_click(self,continue_button,string):
        self.buttonClicked.emit()

    def open_click(self,open_button,string,sheet):
        self.path = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open CSV', os.getenv('HOME'), 'CSV(*.csv)')
        if self.path[0] != '':
            with open(self.path[0], 'rU') as csv_file:
                self.sheet.setRowCount(0)
                my_file = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
                for row_data in my_file:
                    row = self.sheet.rowCount()
                    self.sheet.insertRow(row)
                    self.sheet.setColumnCount(len(row_data))
                    for column, col in enumerate(row_data):
                        item = QTableWidgetItem(col)
                        self.sheet.setItem(row, column, item)
        self.file_path = self.path[0]
        Sheet.email_list = re.findall(r'[\w_]+@[\w_]+\.[\w_]+', open(self.file_path).read())
        EmailList.update_emails(self, Sheet.email_list)        

from email_list import EmailList
```

and finally main.py

```
import sys
import os
import io
from sheet import Sheet
from email_list import EmailList
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QStackedWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt        

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.central_widget = QStackedWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.sheet_widget = Sheet(10,10)        
        self.email_list_widget = EmailList()
        self.central_widget.addWidget(self.sheet_widget)
        self.central_widget.addWidget(self.email_list_widget)
        self.central_widget.setCurrentWidget(self.sheet_widget)

        self.sheet_widget.buttonClicked.connect(lambda: self.central_widget.setCurrentWidget(self.email_list_widget))
        self.sheet_widget.buttonClicked.connect(self.email_list_widget.init_ui)
        self.email_list_widget.buttonClicked.connect(lambda: self.central_widget.setCurrentWidget(self.sheet_widget))

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
run = Main()
run.resize(500,500)
run.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Any help or insight on seamlessly updating a UI from a widget across module would be super! I was thinking of a refresh method, but the email_list already gets updated. The UI should update by itself but it's not, and I am missing something.

Comment: You could try to debug your application. Set breakpoints or print something at the place where the csv files are imported and at the place where the table widget is updated, then, depending on what exactly is not working, try to code a simple example showing exactly this behavior. For example updating a table widget with new content should work independent of where the new data (csv, just a hardcoded list of strings) comes from. This is a very general approach that will also help you later with other problems.

Comment: Agreed with @Trilarion. You are suppose to identify "where" it fails, and then if you can't find a fix for it, google it or come to StackOverflow. Please do not paste to us your entire program, it's too much for us to debug.

Comment: @Trilarion I figured it out, but no amount of debugging or dummy code really helped. I wasn't removing the widgets in the layout. So all the old widgets would lie on top. `self.v_layout.removeWidget(self.email_widget)` `self.email_widget.deleteLater()`

Comment: Glad to hear that you solved the problem yourself although I wonder a bit how you did it if not by debugging and/or inspecting your code.